# Lua Tic Tac Toe Tutorial in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to complete this Lua tic-tac-toe tutorial in Corona SDK.
I managed to get through the [1st part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWVe7YVL7hs) but got lost during this [2nd part](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ZguIa8TZh8) where he is establishing variables within a table to register the alternating turns for "x" and "o".

He is using the tap count to determine which turn it is and I did try to use Corona's touch.id to mimic this technique, to no avail.

I am hoping someone can explain how I can achieve this using Corona.

Here is what I have so far (from Part1 of Tutorial):

```
d = display
w20 = d.contentWidth * .2
h20 = d.contentHeight * .2 
w40 = d.contentWidth * .4
h40 = d.contentHeight * .4
w60 = d.contentWidth * .6
h60 = d.contentHeight * .6
w80 = d.contentWidth * .8
h80 = d.contentHeight * .8


----DRAW LINES FOR BOARD
local lline = d.newLine(w40,h20,w40,h80 )
lline.strokeWidth = 5

local rline = d.newLine(w60,h20,w60,h80 )
rline.strokeWidth = 5

local bline = d.newLine(w20,h40,w80,h40 )
bline.strokeWidth = 5

local tline = d.newLine(w20,h60,w80,h60 )
tline.strokeWidth = 5


--PLACE BOARD COMPARTMENT DIMENSIONS IN TABLE
board ={

    {"tl", 1, w20, h40, w40, h20,0},
    {"tm",2, w40,h40,w60,h20,0},
    {"tr",3, w60,h40,w80,h20,0},

    {"ml", 4, w20, h60, w40, h40,0},
    {"mm",5, w40,h60,w60,h40,0},
    {"mr",6, w60,h60,w80,h40,0},

    {"bl", 7, w20, h80, w40, h60,0},
    {"bm",8, w40,h80,w60,h60,0},
    {"br",9, w60,h80,w80,h60,0}
  }
--

--FILL COMPARTMENT W/ COLOR WHEN TOUCHED
local function fill (event)
  if event.phase == "began" then
    tap =  0

    for t = 1, 9 do
      if event.x > board[t][3] and event.x < board [t][5] then
        if event.y < board[t][4] and event.y > board[t][6] then

          r = d.newRect(board[t][3],board [t][6],w20,h20)
          r:setFillColor(1,1,0)
          r.anchorX=0
          r.anchorY=0
        end
      end
    end 
  end

end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", fill)
```

Comment: I don't understand why "Thank You!!" was removed.

Answer (score 0):

I use new variable `whichTurn` to figure out what to put on board in each turn. I think code is self-explanatory. Try

```
...

local EMPTY, X, O = 0, 1, 2
local whichTurn = X -- X is starting game

... 

--FILL COMPARTMENT W/ COLOR WHEN TOUCHED
local function fill (event)
  if event.phase == "began" then
    for t = 1, 9 do
      if event.x > board[t][3] and event.x < board [t][5] then
        if event.y < board[t][4] and event.y > board[t][6] then
          if board[t][7] == EMPTY then
             board[t][7] = whichTurn
             --[[
             The operator AND returns its first argument if it is false;
             otherwise, it returns its second argument. The operator OR
             returns its first argument if it is not false; otherwise, it
             returns its second argument. 
             --]]
             whichTurn = whichTurn == X and O or X
          end
        end
      end
    end 
  end

end
Runtime:addEventListener("touch", fill)
```

You can read more about differences between tap and touch events in [Corona](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/touchMultitouch/index.html).

Check also this from Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/touchMultitouch/index.html)

> **Filtering Multiple Taps**
>
> Using the `event.numTaps` property, you can easily determine whether an
> object was tapped multiple times and concurrently ignore single taps
> on the object.

Comment: Thanks for the response Idurniat. I've added your code but am having trouble getting it to work. Tables are the bane of my existence. After reviewing your suggested read, I may go another route.

Comment: What do you mean saying 'I am having trouble getting it to work'? I don't add code responsible for drawing Xs and Os on board. So may be this is your problem.

Comment: I actually added my own code for Xs and Os. I meant, I am still having trouble with getting the code, as a whole, to work the way I want it to. I misspoke. Once again I appreciate the help.

Comment: Ok:) May be try tutorials for Corona for example [Memory Matching Game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Juk8pJiU1rw&index=2&list=PLQUSbLhyMnArrQq10_Yv4AblHyQVagxP4), [Brick Breaker](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-brick-breaker-game-with-the-corona-sdk-collision-detection--mobile-5237), [Ping-Pong](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/corona-sdk-create-a-balance-ping-pong-game--mobile-20984?utm_source=Tuts+&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=relatedtutorials&utm_content=sidebar&WT.mc_id=Tuts+_website_relatedtutorials_sidebar). Good luck.